# Deploy angular application on azure

Tags: angular, express, azure-storage, mean, nodejs-8.11

I have frontend app is on angular and backend services on nodejs & express.I want to deploy these apps on Azure. I have used Azure app service to deploy backend app. I was wondering whether we need deploy angular app  using static website(copying dist folder content, generated by ng build) in storage account or we need webserver for that.which is preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting in storage is **simpler** and **less expensive** than maintaining a web server. But since you have your backend app hosted on Azure app service, you can use the same app service plan to reduce cost.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-static-website-node-01